# Split variable into multiple variables

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I understand this has been asked before but the answer don't quite give me what I need. I pgrep for a given string which returns a list of PID's containing that string in a variable ($testpid in this case). I then try and split each one of the PID's out, they are sepereated with a space like so:

PIDS:

```
17717 172132 2138213
```

Code:

```
IFS=" " read -a pidarray <<< "$testpid"
echo pidarray[0]
```

*instead of the echo above i would be assigning each item in the array to its own variable

But I get the following error:

```
syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Comment: That "redirection unexpected" is what you would get if your shell were not in fact bash.

Comment: Your question and the title both seem to indicate that your problem was splitting the PIDs into multiple variables, but you've accepted an answer that deals with a different problem.  If this is in fact what you wanted, please consider rephrasing the title and question accordingly.

Comment: @TTT, an excellent point -- I quite glossed over the note that the actual intent was then to assign the array elements to their own variables; there's no need to use an array at all in that case. Answer amended appropriately.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Do you think that is, indeed what he meant?  I had begun to answer that question, when I saw he marked your original answer as complete.  Regardless, your answer solves both now!

Comment: @TTT, the "instead of the echo above i would be assigning each item in the array to its own variable" makes it fairly clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax was almost correct:

```
IFS=' ' read -r -a pidarray <<< "$testpid"
echo "${pidarray[0]}"
```

Note the curly braces needed for the array dereference.

More importantly, check that your shebang is `#!/bin/bash`, or that you executed your script with `bash yourscript`, not `sh yourscript`. The error given is consistent with a shell that doesn't recognize `<<<` as valid syntax -- which any remotely modern bash always will *when invoked as bash*; even if `/bin/sh` points to the same executable, it tells bash to disable many of its extensions from the POSIX spec.

---

Now, that said -- if your goal is to assign each entry to its own variable, you don't need (and shouldn't use) `read -a` at all!

Instead:

```
IFS=' ' read -r first second third rest <<<"$testpid"
printf '%s\n' "First PID is $first" "Second PID is $second"
```

Comment: Also, `/bin/sh` doesn't support reading array, only :`read [-p prompt] [-r] variable [...]`

Comment: @jujj, indeed; `sh` doesn't support arrays at all, but we don't get to that if we're hitting a syntax error before invoking `read`, so I didn't consider it worth mentioning.

Comment: And if you have a variable number of arguments coming in, you can handle them via looping and the `eval` command, e.g. as `for i in {1..3}; eval "var$i=$i"; done`.  Though, I don't know why you'd want to get away from an array in such an instance, anyway.

Comment: @TTT, there are much better ways to do indirect assignments than `eval`. For instance, `printf -v "var$i" %s "$i"`. See 1.3.3 of http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006 for more (and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 for notes on the eval-considered-harmful premise).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.

```
testpid="17717 172132 2138213"
set -- $testpid
echo -e $1 $2
```

After that use the `$1,$2,$3` to get that separately.

Comment: What does that do that `set -- $testpid` would not, without all the overhead of the subshell?

Comment: To be clear -- I think that if modified to fix the inefficiency (and, maybe, with more explicit note of the side effects -- since it _does_ overwrite the argument list) this is a good answer.

Comment: ...though it also has a problem in the general case of globbing -- the `read -r -a` approach will put a `*` into an array element as a literal, whereas this will replace it with a list of filenames in the current directory. Not a problem with PIDs, but maybe a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Much better. I still might use `--` before the `$testpid` to prevent arguments that start with dashes from being treated as shell options -- what if `$1` were `-e`? -- but that's a relatively minor quibble. (Similar quibbles apply to quoting expansions on arguments to the `echo`).

Comment: Sorry I missed that one.

Comment: Sorry -- I didn't mean to imply supporting `echo -e`. (Quite the contrary, the `-e` argument to bash's `echo` is contrary to the POSIX spec, and goes away if `POSIXLY_CORRECT=1` is defined in the environment).

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html for the POSIX echo spec -- backslash expansion is specified as default with no argument given [on XSI-conformant systems], implementations are prohibited from supporting options other than `-n`, and users are advised to use `printf` instead.

Comment: ...but anyhow, what I meant by "what if $1 were -e" was that we'd be running `set -e`, which is a very different use of `set`.